# What if [whatif] were removed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [whatif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatif) tag has **15 questions** and **no tag wiki.**

- [6 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwhatif%5D+powershell) are about the `-WhatIf` flag common to several (Windows?) PowerShell cmdlets
- [3 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwhatif%5D+powerbi) are about a `What-If` parameter in Power BI
- [6 other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatif) seem to regard a security-related thingy call [the What-If tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64158497/17242583), and others are about [What-If features in data tools/programs like Tensorflow/Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61277929/17242583)

What if we get rid of it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) clearly states that _"What if ___ happened"_ questions aren't allowed. /s

Comment: Yes, remove, and nice title.

Comment: @PCM "What if we get rid of it?" was meant to be a pun on the title and tag, thus the rollback of your edit :)

Comment: Small tag. I cleaned it out, since it had no real purpose

Comment: Great! That wsa easy. My understanding is that any 1.5k+ rep user could re-create it - is that correct @Machavity?

Comment: They could... but there's no obvious synonym